# facebook like button article

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have added facebook like buttons on all the articles on my shop. But whenever someone posts something about the product/article it appears on their wall. (thats good)

the person gets a notification (on facebook), when someone else likes the post. (thats good)

afterwards the person checks the notification (it links to a different site, [https://www.facebook.com/[user]/activity/[id]?notif_t=open_graph_action_like](https://www.facebook.com/%5buser%5d/activity/%5bid%5d?notif_t=open_graph_action_like)).

it says "[linkto: person] likes a product at [linkto: myshop]". Whenever you click on the link to the shop it links you to the app (facebook application) and not to facebook.com/mycompany

how can i change that? is that even possible? or can i somehow redirect? or do i need to change a parameter somewhere?

P.S. i would like to show you the picture but i need at least 10 reputation.^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the "articles" have the neccessary OpenGraph tags. Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-creating to get an idea.